# Can't Install Microsoft.Owin on UWP Projet

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am working on an UWP Projet on Visual Studio 2017.
I just cannot install Microsoft.Owin from the Nuget Package installer.
I am using .NET Framework version 4.7

Here are my errors

```
Restoring packages for c:\users\79037\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Epicture472\Epicture472\Epicture472.csproj...
Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586). Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Owin 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586). Package Owin 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.10586.
Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-arm. Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Owin 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-arm. Package Owin 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-arm).
Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-arm-aot. Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Owin 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-arm-aot. Package Owin 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-arm-aot).
Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x64. Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Owin 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x64. Package Owin 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x64).
Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x64-aot. Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Owin 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x64-aot. Package Owin 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x64-aot).
Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x86. Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Owin 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x86. Package Owin 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x86).
Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x86-aot. Package Microsoft.Owin 3.1.0 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
Package Owin 1.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x86-aot. Package Owin 1.0.0 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.10586 (win10-x86-aot).
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Epicture472'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.4498990
========== Finished ==========
```

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin/1.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error list says; Microsoft.Owin is not compatible with a UWP project. UWP, in fact, does not even run on the .NET Framework (hence the installed version not mattering); rather it runs on .NET Core.

You will need to find a different library that targets a version of .NET Standard UWP implements. Today that would be 1.4 or previous. You can see the current list of platforms and which version of .NET Standard they implement on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

Comment: How do I add NetCore on frameworks available ? I installed NetCore 1.1 and it doesnt appear when I create a new Project

Comment: @Myranova It should be there; sounds like a seperate question